# smtp4dev - access from remote computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

Is it possible to access smtp4dev from a remote computer. I am using smtp4dev locally for development so that I can view emails as my ASP.NET MVC 3 application sends them out. It would nice to be able to do the same one a testing server with the ability for me or a colleage to view messages being generated on that remote testing server.

If smtp4dev can't do it are there any other tools that can? I know it is possible to output files to a share via ASP.NET configuration, but I find smtp4dev to be a much more user friendly experience...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to access you local smtp4dev service from a hosted instance of your project. You have several options:

1. Personally, I use a gmail account for doing this - you're limited to 100 emails per day.
2. Port forward your local smtp4dev service - find the IP address of the computer it's runnning on, the port the service operates on (SMTP port), go to your router and add the port forwarding rule / Virtual Server. It's possible that smtp4dev only bind to the loopback interface, in which case port forwarding won't work. You should also make sure the firewall exception is added for the port or program.
3. Your hosting might already have an SMTP server you can use
4. You could use a public SMTP server - mail.{someisp}.com

In any case, if you're a bit more specific, we will be able to help you further.